# The verb for making others fail their goals

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

If someone makes a plot and efforts to put barriers in someone's way that they fail their goals or don't get success, what idiom is used for this situation?

> A. to cut others' leg
>   B. to cut others' ladder
>   C. to pull others' leg

Can we say:

> X cut Y's legs so that Y doesn't get permission.

Comment: how about x undercuts y so that y doesn't get the permission

Comment: @ Elizabeth [It's all a plot to undermine me.] at https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/undermine.... WILL THIS WORK?

Comment: I think 'undermine' also works fine in this case

Comment: @Elizabeth, Yep. That's what sprang to my mind.

Comment: None of those is used.

Answer (score 2):

There are many terms that could be used, depending on whether they are doing it deliberately, how they do it and how actively they pursue it.

> [hinder](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hinder) - to limit the ability of someone to do something, or to limit the development of something
> [hamper](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hamper) - to prevent someone doing something easily
> [thwart](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thwart) - to stop something from happening or someone from doing something
> [sabotage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sabotage) - to intentionally prevent the success of a plan or action

There are also some informal expressions,for example:

> [put the kibosh on something](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20the%20kibosh%20on)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really use any of those expressions, how about:

> X **got in the way** of Y so that Y doesn't get permission

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression in British English "[to pull the rug out from under someone's feet](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pull_the_rug_out_from_under)" which seems to fit with the examples given in the question.

Note: the third example given "C. to pull others' leg" sounds too much like "[to pull someone's leg](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pull_someone%27s_leg)" which means to tease.